# How to solve "Message content must be a non-empty string" in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Here is my code,

```
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const mineflayer = require("mineflayer");
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });

let sending = false
let chatData = []

let prefix = ".";
var settings = {
    username: "StilShem_tvink",
    host: "mstnw.net",
};

const bot = mineflayer.createBot(settings);

bot.on('kicked', (reason, loggedIn) => console.log(reason, loggedIn));
bot.on('error', err => console.log(err));

client.on("ready", async =>{
    console.log("Discord bot is online!")
})

bot.on("login", async =>{
    console.log("Minecraft bot is online!")
})

bot.on("message", message => {
    if(sending == true) {
        chatData.push(`${message}`)
    }
})

client.on("messageCreate", async msg => {
    let args = msg.content.split(" ").slice(1)

    if(msg.content.startsWith(".chat")) {
        let toSend = args.join(" ");
        if(!toSend) return msg.reply("No args")

        bot.chat(toSend)
        sending = true
        msg.channel.send(`${msg.author.tag} just sent ${toSend}`)

        setTimeout(() => {
            sending = false
            msg.channel.send(chatData.join("\n"))
            chatData = []
        }, 750)
    }
})
```

This code is for minecraft mineflayer with discord. And this code give me error.

> C:\Users\ArtemiiYT\node_modules\discord.js\src\util\Util.js:414
> if (!allowEmpty && data.length === 0) throw new error(errorMessage);
> ^
>
> RangeError [MESSAGE_CONTENT_TYPE]: Message content must be a non-empty
> string.
> at Function.verifyString (C:\Users\ArtemiiYT\node_modules\discord.js\src\util\Util.js:414:49)
> at MessagePayload.makeContent (C:\Users\ArtemiiYT\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\MessagePayload.js:113:22)
> at MessagePayload.resolveData (C:\Users\ArtemiiYT\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\MessagePayload.js:128:26)
> at TextChannel.send (C:\Users\ArtemiiYT\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\TextBasedChannel.js:168:61)
> at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Users\ArtemiiYT\Desktop\Всё\AFK bot\AFKBOTDS\bot.js:46:25)
> at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:557:17)
> at processTimers (node:internal/timers:500:7) {   [Symbol(code)]: 'MESSAGE_CONTENT_TYPE' }
>
> Node.js v17.1.0

Comment: Welcome. Please choose a title which actually describes your problem, so it is searchable for others with the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't go on my way to run the code, but I think the `chatData` array is empty. so when you try to `.join("\n")` all the elements inside it together, you just get an empty string which discord just rejects and you get an error.
so you might want to check if there is anything in the array first.

if you are here for the code just add this in the interval function:

```
if(chatData.length < 1) {
  // maybe inform the user there is no new chat message?
  return;
}
```